# Version.CompareTo incorrect

Tags: c#, version, compareto

I'm comparing two `Version` objects, `2.2.0.59` to `2.1.0.60`, and `CompareTo` seems to be wrong for me.

My code:

```
Version curVersion = new Version("2.2.0.59");
Version newVersion = new Version("2.1.0.60");

void test(){
   if(curVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0){
      Console.WriteLine("New Update Available");
   }
}
```

And the if statement return true.

**From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/a5ts8tb6(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> The components of Version in decreasing order of importance are:
>   major, minor, build, and revision.

Since `newVersion.Minor < curVersion.Minor`, `compareTo` should not return a value > 0 ?

Comment: did you try using another constructor? `Version(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)` ?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: [It’s definitely `false`.](http://ideone.com/OOgQ0f)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5ts8tb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states that the return value is `1` if the current version is greater than the version passed in as a parameter to `CompareTo()`.

In `curVersion.CompareTo(newVersion)`, the current version is `curVersion` which is greater than `newVersion` (because of the `Minor` field difference), so the return value is `1`.

Alternatively, you can also use

```
if ( newVersion > curVersion )
{
    // There's a newer version available, do your magic
}
```

for a more readable check. This returns the same result as `CompareTo()` would (for the equivalent check) but is easier to understand.